# Get statistics of iTunes usage

Tags: mac, itunes

I wonder if there us any program/web service for Mac, that can display full statistics about iTunes usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [iTunes Statistician](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20494/itunes-statistician/) that gives some stats about your iTunes usage : time spent to listen to music, songs played per days, top songs/artists/albums, etc.

Hope that helps.